# failed to connect webpage to MQTT broker using paho-mqtt-javascript

Tags: websocket, mqtt, paho

I'm using a mosquitto MQTT broker (ip:192.168.1.61 and port:1883)
here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My First Value</title>
<h1>Main Body</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<h1><div id="connstatus">
Mqtt Not connected.</div></h1>
</body>
<script>

var host = "192.168.1.61";
var port=1883;
var user="Fares";
var pass="1+4=5";
// Create a client instance
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,1883, "clientId");

// set callback handlers
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});


// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("World");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "World";
  client.send(message);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
</script>
</html>
```

here is my .config file:

> listener 8883
>
> keyfile /mosquitto/config/certs/broker.key
>
> listener 8083 protocol websockets
>
> keyfile /mosquitto/config/certs/broker.key
>
> require_certificate false
>
> persistence true persistence_location /mosquitto/data/

errors:
console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.61:1883/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._doConnect @   mqttws31.js:977
Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._disconnected  @   mqttws31.js:1459
Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._on_socket_error   @   mqttws31.js:1347
(anonymous) @   mqttws31.js:157
```

[image: cmd]

Comment: Please do not post images of text, the log file should be posted as text and formatted (e.g. as code).  As it is it is hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers or to search for.

Comment: got it,sorry, I'm gonna edit it

Comment: I meant both logs.

Answer (score 2):

Port 1883 is the default for Native MQTT, not MQTT over WebSockets.

The Paho Javascript driver requires the broker to support and be configured to accept connections from clients using MQTT over WebSockets.

Your mosquitto.conf looks a little screwy (protocol elements should be on their own line), it should look like this:

```
listener 8883
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certs/broker.key

listener 8083
protocol websockets
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certs/broker.key
require_certificate false

persistence true persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
```

It appears you have configured the WebSocket listener on port `8083` so your code should be using that not `1883`

```
var host = "192.168.1.61";
var port= 8083;
```

Also to enable MQTT over TLS and MQTT over Secure Websockets you are going to need to include a `certfile` entry as well as a `keyfile`